# Пулл базы данных

Tags: развертывание, mysql

Все привет, интересует вопрос.
Если все участники проекта работают локально, как проще всего им скачивать текущую базу данных + какое-ту часть данных для работы? Как это делается в крупных конторах?

Comment: Не скажу за крупные конторы (я имею в виду айти отдел какого-нибудь крупного производства), но при разработке проекта вообще очень полезно использовать миграции (хорошей статьи типа википедии не нашел, можно посмотреть, как это делается в [yii1](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.migration)). Это позволяет любому человеку развернуть у себя БД любой версии, при хорошей организации - не только, скажем, на mysql, но и на других серверах БД. Остается вопрос с наполнением данными - есть понятие фикстур, но их очень муторно вести для каждой версии БД.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону  http://www.liquibase.org

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если я все правильно понял - то в liquibase происходит контроль структуры базы данных, а что происходит с самими данными?

Если я подключаюсь к разработке проекта с большой базой, какой доступ мне дадут к данным?

Comment: С данными будет происходит ровно то, что с нимы вы будете делать.
Ну видимо какой доступ вы попросите такой вам и предоставят. 
liquibase позволяет управлять структурой данных через систему контроля версий и выполнять миграции в крупных проектах с развесистой структурой таблиц. На хабре есть статьи по применению этого ПО в разработке.